# Typescript: Difficulty typing react-redux "Connect" helper function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am running a Typescript React application that uses Redux. I just upgraded to the latest version of redux (4.1.2 as of this post) from 3.7. One thing I have found troublesome about redux is the amount of setup code needed to connect a component, so I decided to write a helper function for connect. The goal is to write a connect function that takes a component and a set of props to include from the state and/or dispatch. Here is what I had working before my update to 4.1.2:

A factory that creates the mapStateToProps function:

```
type StoreKey = keyof MyAppState;  // MyAppState is a sub-state of the global application state
type AppState<K extends StoreKey = StoreKey> = Pick<MyAppState, K>;

// The 'only' array will be a set of props. For example: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']
const mapStateToPropsFactory = <K extends StoreKey>(only?: K[]) =>
{
    if (!only || only.length === 0)
    {
        return function (state: GlobalApplicationState): AppState<K>
        {
            return { ...state.myAppState }
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return function (state: GlobalApplicationState): AppState<K>
        {
            let storeKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(state.myAppState) as K[];
            return storeKeys.reduce((result, key) =>
            {
                if (arrayIncludes(only, key))
                {
                    result[key] = state.myAppState[key];
                }

                return result;
            }, {} as AppState<K>);
        }
    }
}
```

The helper function:

```
export function reduxConnectState<P extends AppState<K>, K extends StoreKey>(componentType: React.ComponentType<P>, ...only: K[])
{
    return connect(mapStateToPropsFactory<K>(only))(componentType);
}

// Usage:
export default reduxConnectState(MyComponent, "prop1", "prop2", "prop3");
```

Unfortunately, after the update the typings broke. The error I'm getting is from the helper function, specifically passing componentType into the result of connect:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ComponentType<P>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<any, P | (ClassAttributes<Component<P, any, any>> & P)>>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<P, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Matching<any, P | (ClassAttributes<Component<P, any, any>> & P)>>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<P, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<any, P | (ClassAttributes<Component<P, any, any>> & P)>, any>'.
      Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
        Type 'WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<any, P | (ClassAttributes<Component<P, any, any>> & P)>> | undefined'.
          Type 'WeakValidationMap<P>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<any, P | (ClassAttributes<Component<P, any, any>> & P)>> | undefined'.
            Type 'WeakValidationMap<P>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<any, P>>'.
              Type '(null extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & undefined) | null> : Validator<...>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>) | undefined'.
                Type 'null extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & undefined) | null> : Validator<...>' is not assignable to type '(null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>) | undefined'.
                  Type 'Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined> | (undefined extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & undefined) | null> : Validator<P[K]>)' is not assignable to type '(null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>) | undefined'.
                    Type 'Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>'.
                      Type 'null extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & undefined) | null> : Validator<...>' is not assignable to type 'null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>'.
                        Type 'Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined> | (undefined extends P[K] ? Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & undefined) | null> : Validator<P[K]>)' is not assignable to type 'null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>'.
                          Type 'Validator<P[K] | (P[K] & null) | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'null extends Matching<any, P>[K] ? Validator<Matching<any, P>[K] | (Matching<any, P>[K] & null) | undefined> : undefined extends Matching<...>[K] ? Validator<...> : Validator<...>'.
```

To be honest, I've looked at the new types in the redux files and I have no idea what the issue is here. I tried the following as an experiment:

```
export function reduxConnectState<T extends React.ComponentType<P>, P extends AppState<K>, K extends StoreKey>(componentType: T, ...only: K[])
{
    return connect(mapStateToPropsFactory<K>(only))(componentType);
}
```

But that left me with a different error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'ComponentType<P>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<ContentEditorState<K> & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, GetProps<T>>>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<P, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Matching<ContentEditorState<K> & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, GetProps<T>>>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<P, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Matching<ContentEditorState<K> & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, GetProps<T>>, any>'.
      Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
        Type 'WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<ContentEditorState<K> & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, GetProps<T>>> | undefined'.
          Type 'WeakValidationMap<P>' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<ContentEditorState<K> & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, GetProps<T>>>'.
            Type 'keyof GetProps<T>' is not assignable to type 'keyof P'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof P'.
                Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K'.
                  'K' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly one of the reasons why [we now teach using the hooks API as the default](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure#the-react-counter-component), instead of `connect`.  The hooks API is *much* easier to use with TS.

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, I would *strongly* recommend rewriting your components to call `useSelector` instead of `connect`.  It will almost definitely be much less work than trying to get this "wrapper around the `connect` wrapper" to work correctly with TS :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I may end up going that way in the future. However, I have hundreds of components and a full refactor isn't in the cards at this time.

Comment: I still would _not_ recommend trying to write a wrapper around `connect` itself.  If you truly feel the need to abstract this, I would suggest writing a function that just generates the `mapState` part, and then call `connect(myMapState)(MyComponent)` as usual. Also see https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically for our recommended approach for inferring the props from `connect` automatically.